# Why is the data displayed after a `merge` different from the actual dataframe in pandas and jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I merge three dataframes, but the result displayed is different than the actual result. I want the result displayed.

Here is the merge code:

```
df_twitter_archive_clean_test.merge(df_tweets_clean_test, on='tweet_id', how='left')
df_twitter_archive_clean_test.merge(df_images_clean_test, on='tweet_id')
```

Here is part of the result that pops up after running this code:

```
tweet_id    in_reply_to_status_id   in_reply_to_user_id     timestamp   source  text    retweeted_status_id     retweeted_status_user_id    retweeted_status_timestamp  expanded_urls   rating_numerator    rating_denominator  name    doggo   floofer     pupper  puppo   jpg_url     img_num     p1  p1_conf     p1_dog  p2  p2_conf     p2_dog  p3  p3_conf     p3_dog
```

That result has 28 columns.

But when I run `df_twitter_archive_clean_test.info()` I get 17 columns!

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2356 entries, 0 to 2355
Data columns (total 17 columns):
tweet_id                      2356 non-null object
in_reply_to_status_id         78 non-null float64
in_reply_to_user_id           78 non-null float64
timestamp                     2356 non-null object
source                        2356 non-null object
text                          2356 non-null object
retweeted_status_id           181 non-null float64
retweeted_status_user_id      181 non-null float64
retweeted_status_timestamp    181 non-null object
expanded_urls                 2297 non-null object
rating_numerator              2356 non-null int64
rating_denominator            2356 non-null int64
name                          2356 non-null object
doggo                         2356 non-null object
floofer                       2356 non-null object
pupper                        2356 non-null object
puppo                         2356 non-null object
dtypes: float64(4), int64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 313.0+ KB
```

Testing the data reveals that the dataset has 17 columns.

How can I stop this mysterious change?

Comment: `left_df.merge(right_df)` does not modify `left_df` or `right_df`. If you want the result, you need to assign it to a variable (`result_df = left_df.merge(right_df)`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not copying or defining a new variable after the merge therefore you get the information `df_twitter_archive_clean_test` pre-merge. This can sometimes be solved with an extra parameter called `in_place` which basically defines if after applying a function to an existing dataframe, changes will be saved in that dataframe, or if assigning the changes to a new dataframe must be done to keep the changes.
If you wish to solve this you can try:

```
semi_merged_df = df_twitter_archive_clean_test.merge(df_tweets_clean_test, on='tweet_id', how='left')
merged_df = semi_merged_df.merge(df_images_clean_test, on='tweet_id')
```

And finally

```
print(merged_df.info())
```

Should return your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the merge code to this seems to get of the problem:

```
df_master = pd.merge(df_twitter_archive_clean_test, df_images_clean_test, how = 'left', on = ['tweet_id'] )
df_master = pd.merge(df_master, df_tweets_clean_test, how = 'left', on = ['tweet_id'])
```

I don't know why,

Comment: I explained it in my answer.